# Connection pool detection

Tags: mysql, netbeans, glassfish, datasource, connection-pooling

I am creating an application in java using glassfish server in netbeans. I've created connection pool and data source for sql query execution. I have created a sample jsp page to check the transection using connection pool which is as follows.

And as I run this file in browser I get this internal error.

> "javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution!! :)

The problem was. I didn't set password for mysql. At the time setting up a new connection pool, providing password is mendatory. so I just added the password and now it is working. I hope if anybody else faces the problem then it would be helpful

Comment: You can check the connection by using the "Ping Connection" facility in Glassfish admin console: http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/